# IE XDR with jQuery fails on remote web host but not local computer

Tags: internet-explorer, local, remote-server, xdr

This *exact* code works when loading the HTML file from my local computer but not while running on my remote host.  I'm using the same code as is in the xdr.js jQuery plugin.  The error object I print out has a statusText of "Error: Access is denied."

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ( window.XDomainRequest ) {
            jQuery.ajaxTransport = function( s ) {
                if ( s.crossDomain && s.async ) {
                    if ( s.timeout ) {
                        s.xdrTimeout = s.timeout;
                        delete s.timeout;
                    }
                    var xdr;
                    return {
                        send: function( _, complete ) {
                            function callback( status, statusText, responses, responseHeaders ) {
                                xdr.onload = xdr.onerror = xdr.ontimeout = jQuery.noop;
                                xdr = undefined;
                                complete( status, statusText, responses, responseHeaders );
                            }
                            xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                            xdr.onload = function() {
                                callback( 200, "OK", { text: xdr.responseText }, "Content-Type: " + xdr.contentType );
                            };
                            xdr.onerror = function() {
                                callback( 404, "Not Found" );
                            };
                            xdr.onprogress = jQuery.noop;
                            xdr.ontimeout = function() {
                                callback( 0, "timeout" );
                            };
                            xdr.timeout = s.xdrTimeout || Number.MAX_VALUE;
                            xdr.open( s.type, s.url );
                            xdr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
                        },
                        abort: function() {
                            if ( xdr ) {
                                xdr.onerror = jQuery.noop;
                                xdr.abort();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            };

        }
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var hash = '9lWA8';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/'+hash,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID 60512304ac2e7ce');},
            success: function(data) {
                console.dir(data.data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.dir(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head

<body>
</body>

</html>
```